# way to parse the value in attribute using PullParser

Tags: android

I want to parse the google weather Api response..
     the response is like :

now i want only temp_c data to use in my app.
so how can i get the value of temp using xml pull parser..

right now i m doing like that

```
   StringBufferInputStream buffer = new StringBufferInputStream(response);
        xpp = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance().newPullParser();
        xpp.setInput(buffer, null);
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
        {


            if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG){

                String elementName = xpp.getName();
                if(elementName.equals("current_conditions")){
                    local_pickup = xpp.nextText();
                    Log.d("database", local_pickup);
                }
                       }
                   eventType = xpp.next();
        }
        buffer.close();
```

please help me guys as early as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution for this problem in the following link [how to parse the value in the attribute in xml parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827168/how-to-parse-the-value-in-the-attribute-in-xml-parsing)

But parsing using SAX parser is more efficient for these type XML files. check this link for parsing your XML easily using SAX parser http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/SAXDemo.htm