# Parse XML that contains more than one attribute

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am parsing a big XML document using a SAX parser, but after seeing an example of SAX parsing on Google, I am unable to parse this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<school title="The Clifton School" icon="" browserBackButtonTitle = "Clifton App" navBarColor = "#7eb432">
    <screen id = "1" backgroundColor = "" backgroundImg = "" templateId = "12" hasNavigationBar = "0" hasTabBar = "1" >
        <navigation-bar title = "" color = "#7eb432" backButtonTitle = "Back">
            <!--<navigation-item type = "1" action = "" />-->
        </navigation-bar>
        <tab-bar numberOfTabs = "4" >
            <tab-bar-item title = "Home" image = "tab_home.png" linkedScreen = "101" />
            <tab-bar-item title = "Calendar" image = "tab_calendar.png" linkedScreen = "102" />
            <tab-bar-item title = "Menu" image = "tab_menu.png" linkedScreen = "604" />
            <tab-bar-item title = "Directions" image = "tab_directions.png" linkedScreen = "401" />
            <tab-bar-item title = "Contact" image = "tab_contact.png" linkedScreen = "206" />
        </tab-bar>
    </screen>
```

This is not whole XML document. For parsing that, I made 5 property classes:

1) `School`

```
public class School 
{
    public String title;
    public String icon="";
    public String browserBackButtonTitle;
    public String navBarColor;
    public ArrayList<Screen> screenlist = new ArrayList<Screen>();
}
```

2) `Screen`

```
public class Screen 
{
    public String Id;
    public String backgroundColor;
    public String backgroundImg ; 
    public String templateId;
    public String hasNavigationBar;
    public String hasTabBar;
    public ArrayList<NavigationBar> objlistofNB = new ArrayList<NavigationBar>();
}
```

3) `NavigationBar`

```
public class NavigationBar 
{
    public String title;
    public String  color;
    public String backButtonTitle;
}
```

4) `ScreenTabBar`

```
public class ScreenTabBar
{
    private int numberOfTabs;
    private ArrayList<TabBarItem> objlistofTabBarItem = new ArrayList<TabBarItem>();
}
```

5) `TabBarItem`

```
public class TabBarItem
{
    public String Title;
    public String image;
    public String linkedScreen;
}
```

I overrode the `startElement` method in which I can't do how apply exact codition-

```
@Override
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
{
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
    currentElement = true;

    if (localName.equals("school"))
    {
        /** Start */
        objschool = new School();
        schoolmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        schoolmap.put("school_name", attributes.getValue("title"));
        schoolmap.put("school_icon", attributes.getValue("icon"));
        schoolmap.put("school_browserBackButtonTitle", attributes.getValue("browserBackButtonTitle"));
        schoolmap.put("school_navBarColor", attributes.getValue("navBarColor"));
        objschool = (School)parseProperty(objschool,schoolmap);
    }
    else if (localName.equals("screen"))
    {
        /** Get attribute value */
        objscreen = new Screen();
        screenmap.put("screen_id", attributes.getValue("id"));
        screenmap.put("screen_backgroundColor", attributes.getValue("backgroundColor"));
        screenmap.put("screen_backgroundImg",attributes.getValue("backgroundImg"));
        screenmap.put("screen_templateId",attributes.getValue("templateId"));
        screenmap.put("screen_hasNavigationBar",attributes.getValue("hasNavigationBar"));
        screenmap.put("screen_hasTabBar",attributes.getValue("hasTabBar"));
        objscreen =(Screen)parseProperty(objscreen,screenmap);
    }
    else if (localName.equals("navigation-bar"))
    {
        objnavBar = new NavigationBar();
        navimap.put("naviTitle",attributes.getValue("title"));
        navimap.put("navicolor",attributes.getValue("color"));
        navimap.put("navibackButtonTitle",attributes.getValue("backButtonTitle"));
        objnavBar =(NavigationBar)parseProperty(objnavBar,navimap);
    }
    else if (localName.equals("tab-bar"))
    {
        objtabBar = new ScreenTabBar();
        tabbarmap.put("numberOfTabs",attributes.getValue("numberOfTabs"));
        objtabBar = (ScreenTabBar)parseProperty(objtabBar, tabbarmap);
    }
    else if (localName.equals("tab-bar-item"))
    {
        objtabBaritem = new TabBarItem();
        tabbarmap.put("Title",attributes.getValue("title"));
        tabbarmap.put("Image",attributes.getValue("image"));
        tabbarmap.put("LinkedScreen",attributes.getValue("linkedScreen"));
    }
}
```

The `parseProperty` method is:

```
private Object parseProperty(Object t, Map<String,String> list) 
{
    Class c=null;
    String className[]=t.toString().split("@");
    try {
        String s = t.toString();
        c = Class.forName(className[0]);
        Field[] f = c.getDeclaredFields();
        //for(int i=0; i<list.entrySet().size();i++)
        //{
        for (String key : list.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("key/value: " + key + "/"+list.get(key));
            String attrname = key;
            for(int j=0; j<f.length;j++)
            {
                String s2=f[j].getName();
                if(s2.equals(attrname))
                {
                    f[j].set(t,list.get(key));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return t;
}
```

How I can parse the above XML by the above rules which were applied by me?

Comment: You seem to be using a SAX Parser. Take a look at the DOM parser, I'd wager you'll find it much easier to reason about. You can google "android dom parser" and get resources.

Comment: but xml size is very big can I use?

Comment: How big is "very big"? If "very" is indeed DOM-prohibitively big, I'd still take a look at other parsers. Blindly writing SAX (specially in Java) is a sneaky and time-consuming task. If you need a smaller memory footprint, Android has a PULL parser that works pretty much like SAX but has a (in my opinion) saner interface.

Comment: 30kb? That's nothing. Go for DOM. EDIT -- unless *speed* is also an issue. Do you want to asynchronously process the document as it is read, or can you afford to wait for the DOM parser?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827168/how-to-parse-the-value-in-the-attribute-in-xml-parsing

check this link...Hope it will help you...

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is

Comment: @njzk2 I unnable to parse but did above code but how set arraylist of screen in School class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Please try this code you need to use correct position of tags.Hope this code will works

```
InputStream in =response.getEntity().getContent();

            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(in);
            String responseCode = "";
            String extendedMessage = "";
            if (doc != null) {
                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("school");
                if (nl.getLength() > 0) {
                    Node node = nl.item(positionof tab-bar);
                   Node node1= node.getChildNodes().item(position of tab-bar-item);
                responseCode = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("title");
            }
```

Please find the following code i parsed almost all child nodes and attribute values within readxml function as i dont have the link of that xml i used assets folder to read that xml file.With in sop statements can find how to get values from child nodes as well as attributes

```
public class XMLSaxParse extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    AssetManager assetManager;
    InputStream inputStream;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
       try {
        inputStream=getAssets().open("sam.xml",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        readXML();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    }

    public void readXML()
    {


        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                    .newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(inputStream);
            if (doc != null) {
                NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName("screen");
                NodeList nodeList=doc.getChildNodes();
                System.out.println("Length of NodeList...................................");
               System.out.println("Displays id node name from screen tag..................................."+nl.item(0).getAttributes().item(0).getNodeName());
               System.out.println("Displays id node value from screen tag..................................."+nl.item(0).getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue());
               System.out.println("Displays naviagtionbar node name (child node)..................................."+nl.item(0).getChildNodes().item(1).getNodeName());
               System.out.println("Displays naviagtionbar node Value: (child node)"+nl.item(0).getChildNodes().item(1).getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue());
               System.out.println("Displays tabbar node name (child node)..................................."+nl.item(0).getChildNodes().item(3).getNodeName());
               System.out.println("Displays tabbar node Value (child node)..................................."+nl.item(0).getChildNodes().item(3).getNodeValue());
               System.out.println("Displays tabbaritem node name (child node of tab-bar)..................................."+nl.item(0).getChildNodes().item(3).getChildNodes().item(1).getNodeName());
               System.out.println("Displays tabbaritem node Value (child node of tab-bar)..................................."+nl.item(0).getChildNodes().item(3).getChildNodes().item(1).getAttributes().item(0).getNodeValue());
                if (nl.getLength() > 0) {
                    Node node = nl.item(0);
                   Node node1= node.getChildNodes().item(0);

              /*  NamedNodeMap responseCode1 = node1.getAttributes();
               Node ex= responseCode1.getNamedItem("title");*/
               System.out.println("data displaying.............................."+node.getNodeValue());
            }

   }
        } catch (DOMException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for proper guidence,but school is root node and screen,navbar,tabbar are child nodes how I can parse it because it is not working..

Comment: Because you copy-pasted the answer, which is not "properly guided"! Take my advice, read about parsing a DOM in Java (google that!), you'll at least understand what you're doing