# Parsing XML file return null;

Tags: android, xml-parsing

I want to parse xml file as follow:

```
     <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
     <rsp status='ok'>
           <status_id>1111</status_id>
           <user_id>TwitUsername</user_id>
           <media_id>ZZ83F</media_id> 
      </rsp>
```

I use DOM to parse file xml as follow:

```
public String getStatus()
    {       
    String status="";
    try {           
        InputStream is=this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.json);
        Document xmlDoc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
        Element root = xmlDoc.getDocumentElement();         
        NodeList rsp = root.getElementsByTagName("rsp");            
        for(int i=0;i<rsp.getLength();i++)
        {
             Node curNode = rsp.item(i);
             // this tag is <study>, get `id` attribute first
             status=String.valueOf(((Attr)curNode.getAttributes().item(0)).getValue());              
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return status;
}
```

But *getStatus* method return null.

Comment: Please read the following 2 min tutorial: http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html

Comment: He isnt asking to parse XML rather he is asking to parse Attributes.

Comment: He's first line is: I want to parse file xml, and also, in his question itself, he said he does not know how to parse xml file. I was trying to help him, so please see his question and then criticize.

Comment: *Parse file XML special* If haven't status=ok ...?

Comment: So I guess, its part of parsing XML file itself, right?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.jondev.net/articles/Android_XML_SAX_Parser_Example

```
 @Override
    public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, 
            Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        if (localName.equals("rsp")) {
              System.out.println("The value of attribute 'status' is: " + atts.getValue("status"));
        }   
    }
```

Comment: if using XmlPullParser http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827168/how-to-parse-the-value-in-the-attribute-in-xml-parsing

Comment: if Using DOMParser http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using.html

Comment: I edited my question?.I want to parse file xml by DOM becasue SAX is very long?Can you help me?

Comment: I done as you write but it's not work..I change status=String.valueOf(((Attr)curNode.getAttributes().item(0)).getValue()); it also not work :(

Comment: can you put the breakpoint at this line  curNode.getAttributes("status") and check curNode attributes and their keys ?

Comment: Here curNode only have method getAttributes(),it haven't method getAttribute("attribue");

Comment: Element curNode = (Element )rsp.item(i);                          curNode .getAttribute("status")

Answer (score 0):

try this method

```
public void getGeoLocation(Document doc)throws IOException {

    NodeList nodeList, nchild;
    Node currentNode, thisNode;
    nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("rsp");
    int length = nodeList.getLength();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        currentNode = nodeList.item(i);
        nchild = currentNode.getChildNodes();
        int clength = nchild.getLength();

        for (int j = 0; j < clength; j++) {

            thisNode = nchild.item(j);

            if ("rsp".equals(thisNode.getNodeName())) {

                        org.w3c.dom.Element e1 = (org.w3c.dom.Element) thisNode;
                        String status = e1.getAttribute("status");

            }
            if ("status_id".equals(thisNode.getNodeName())) {

                String status_id =  thisNode.getTextContent();
            }
            if ("user_id".equals(thisNode.getNodeName())) {

                String user_id =  thisNode.getTextContent();
            }
            if ("media_id".equals(thisNode.getNodeName())) {

                String media_id =  thisNode.getTextContent();
            }
        }
    }

}
```