# How to parser attributes with XmlPullParser?

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I have this xml structure:

```
<markers>
<marker provincia="Guayas" lat="-2.33" lng="-77.63" />
<marker provincia="Pichincha" lat="-3.23" lng="-81.13" />
</markers>
```

and I want to show it in a listview. I have based in this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40mYDQkK44A&list=LLOrnnW9CcIjiJZZ8klyz47g&index=1) but this have other xml structure. I think I need to put the parameter getAttributeCount(), I found this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827168/how-to-parse-the-value-in-the-attribute-in-xml-parsing) but I don´t understand very well. Can you guide me?. This is the code modify:

```
package com.makemyandroidapp.example.stacksites;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import android.content.Context;

public class SitesXmlPullParser {

    static String KEY_MARKER = "marker";

    public static List<StackSite> getStackSitesFromFile(Context ctx) {
        List<StackSite> stackSites;
        stackSites = new ArrayList<StackSite>();

        try {
            // Get our factory and PullParser
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            // Open up InputStream and Reader of our file.
            FileInputStream fis = ctx.openFileInput("StackSites.xml");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            xpp.setInput(reader);
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                String tagname = xpp.getName();

                switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:

                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equals(KEY_MARKER)) {
                        KEY_MARKER = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "provincia");
                        KEY_MARKER = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "lat");
                        KEY_MARKER = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "lng");    
                    } 
                        else{
                    } 
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
                //move on to next iteration
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // return the populated list.
        return stackSites;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use this example http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/  and  http://androidexample.com/XML_Parsing_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=69&aaid=94  .Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the links but These are not what I' m looking for exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution for this:

```
public class SitesXmlPullParser {
    static final String KEY_MARKERS = "markers";
    static final String KEY_MARKER= "marker";

    public static List<StackSite> getStackSitesFromFile(Context ctx) {

        // List of StackSites that we will return
        List<StackSite> stackSites;
        stackSites = new ArrayList<StackSite>();

        // temp holder for current StackSite while parsing
        StackSite curStackSite = null;          

        try {
            // Get our factory and PullParser
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            // Open up InputStream and Reader of our file.
            FileInputStream fis = ctx.openFileInput("StackSites.xml");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

            // point the parser to our file.
            xpp.setInput(reader);

            // get initial eventType
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            // Loop through pull events until we reach END_DOCUMENT
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                // Get the current tag
                String tagname = xpp.getName();

                // React to different event types appropriately
                switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase(KEY_MARKER)) {
                        // If we are starting a new <markers> block we need
                        //a new StackSite object to represent it
                        curStackSite = new StackSite();
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:                 
                    if (tagname.equals(KEY_MARKER)) {                                                       
                        String title = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "provincia");                
                        String lat = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "lat");
                        String lng = xpp.getAttributeValue(null, "lng");                        
                        curStackSite.setTitulo(title);                      
                        curStackSite.setLat(lat);
                        curStackSite.setLng(lng);                       
                        stackSites.add(curStackSite);                                   
                    }                   
                    break;
                default:
                    break;              }
                //move on to next iteration
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return the populated list.
        return stackSites;
    }
}
```